# facet_wrap() in ggplot with a combination of math expressions and a string

Tags: r, ggplot2, expression, facet-wrap

I have a data frame with single continuous variable (`x`) and a categorical variable (`id`). Data are generated as:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(id = rep(1:9, each = 50), x = rnorm(450)) %>%
    mutate(id = replace(id, id == 9, "BLA"))
```

A plot I'm considering is generated using the following lines of code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x)) +
    geom_histogram() +
    facet_wrap(~ id, labeller = labeller(id = facet_names))
```

where a `facet_names` object is defined as a mapping vector:

```
facet_names <- c(
    `1` = expression(i[1]),
    `2` = expression(i[2]),
    `3` = expression(i[3]),
    `4` = expression(i[4]),
    `5` = expression(i[5]),
    `6` = expression(i[6]),
    `7` = expression(i[7]),
    `8` = expression(i[8]),
    `9` = "BLA"
)
```

I wonder how to format the labels in a `facet_wrap` call as i<sub>1</sub>, i<sub>2</sub>, ..., i<sub>8</sub>, BLA

However, in the current settings, the labels are plotted as 1, 2, ..., BLA (i.e., without letter "i" and a number in a subscript).

Thanks for any pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to convert `id` to a factor with levels specified in `facet_names` and then use `label_parsed` as the labeller function, interpreting the labels as plotmath expressions:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- mutate_at(df, .vars = "id", .funs = factor, labels = facet_names)

ggplot(df, aes(x = x)) +
    geom_histogram() +
    facet_wrap(~ id, labeller = label_parsed)
```

[image]